# array of rectangles without d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Here is some d3.js to build a grid of squares:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        d3.select("#board")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 10 + 60*i)
        .attr("y", 10 + 60*j)
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height",50); 
    }
}
```

how do I draw the `<rect>` elements directly with `svg`?

Answer (score 2):

You mean without d3? Using the DOM, like this...

```
var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
rect.setAttribute("x", 10);
...
```

or as markup

```
<rect x="<some number>" y="<some other number>" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want lots of identical objects, you can use the `<use>` tag to create copies of an object mentioned in  the `<defs>` section. This save you from having to repeat all the presentation attributes (`width`, `height`, `fill`, etc.).

```html
<svg viewBow="0 0 400 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <rect id="square" width="40" height="40" fill="#ff0" stroke="#f60" stroke-width="5" />
  </defs>
  <!-- Create as many rectangles as you need: -->
  <use x="5" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="55" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="105" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="155" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="205" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="255" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="305" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="355" y="5" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="5" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="55" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="105" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="155" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="205" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="255" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="305" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
  <use x="455" y="55" xlink:href="#square" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's rather heavy on memory/performance unless you specifically need the feature that updating the master updates all the references.

Comment: @RobertLongson Depends on how many rectangles you want, I suppose. If "direct with SVG" means "using Javascript", I'd probably go with your answer.